# Can anyone help me write an xpath expression to select repeating nodes with duplicate cdata elements when they’re in staggered order

Tags: xml, xpath, expression, xpath-2.0, xpathnavigator

```
<records>
    <record>
        <field_values>
            <field_value name="PSH" reportable="False">
                <item>
                <column name="procedure"><![CDATA[Duplicate1]]></column>
                <column name="comment"><![CDATA[]]></column>
                <column name="date"><![CDATA[1982]]></column>
                </item>
                <item>
                <column name="procedure"><![CDATA[Duplicate2]]></column>
                <column name="comment"><![CDATA[]]></column>
                <column name="date"><![CDATA[1999]]></column>
                </item>
                <item>
                <column name="procedure"><![CDATA[Duplicate1]]></column>
                <column name="comment"><![CDATA[]]></column>
                <column name="date"><![CDATA[1982]]></column>
                </item>
                <item>
                <column name="procedure"><![CDATA[Duplicate2]]></column>
                <column name="comment"><![CDATA[]]></column>
                <column name="date"><![CDATA[1999]]></column>
                </item>
            </field_value>
        </field_values>
    </record>
</records>
```

I am new to xpath expressions and I need to figure out an expression that selects duplicate items of this particular node to delete.  I am only able to create the following expression:

/records/record/field_values/field_value[@name="PSH"]/item

Can someone assist me in finding a expression to select the duplicated items of the node?

Answer (score 0):

```
distinct-values(/records/record/field_values/field_value[@name="PSH"]/item/column[@name='procedure'])
```

Comment: My intent is to select the duplicated set of item elements, so one of the duplicate set of "duplicate1" and "duplicate2"

Comment: I updated the experssion , that should yield one set of duplicate1, 2, and it needs xpath 2.0

Comment: Great :) thank you so much.  Do you know if there is an expression to capture the entire item that includes the procedure, comment, and date attribute and values as oppose to just the column with the "procedure" attribute?

Comment: is there an alternative expression for xpath1.0?